# Automapper to manually map some fields then handle the rest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have this automapper:

```
namespace App.Mappings
{
    public class AutoMapperModelOne : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperModelOne()
        {
            CreateMap<JToken, ModelOne>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("application_id")))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.activity_created, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("activity_created")))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.source_url, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("source_url")))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.is_transferred, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("is_transferred")));
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to automatically map the token values to the model values. But some fields should be ignored and some selected fields have a different token key compared to the model properties.

Something like this:

```
namespace App.Mappings
{
    public class AutoMapperModelOne : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperModelOne()
        {
            CreateMap<JToken, RAFApplication>()
            // manually mapping this field to the id
            .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken("application_id")))
            // ignoring this field
            .ForMember(dest => dest.actualId, opt => opt.Ignore())
            // mapping specific fields first the mapping all others?
            .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken(opt.DestinationMember.Name)));
        }
    }
}
```

The second block of code currently does not work and it produces an error thrown by my fluent validator:

[image]

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the map rules you defined in ForMember would be overrided in that in ForAllMember
You could try as below:

```
public AutoMapperModelOne()
        {
            CreateMap<JToken, ModelOne>()                           
                
                .ForAllMembers(opt =>
                {
                    opt.MapFrom( src=> opt.DestinationMember.Name=="Id"?src.SelectToken("appid"): src.SelectToken(opt.DestinationMember.Name)) ;

                    opt.Condition((src, des, arg3, arg4, resolutionContext) =>
                    {
                        var propname = opt.DestinationMember.Name;
                        if (propname == "Prop1")
                        {                            
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
                    });


        }
```

Model class:

```
 public class ModelOne
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Prop1 { get; set; }

        public string? Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string? Prop3 { get; set; }
        public string? Prop4 { get; set; }

    }
```

Map

```
var obj = new {appid=1,Prop1="val1",Prop2="val2",Prop3="val3",Prop4="val4"};
    var jtoken = JToken.FromObject(obj);
    var targetmodel = mapper.Map<ModelOne>(jtoken);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336870/mapping-profiles-not-mapping-to-correct-model

Comment: Helloo, what if any property is null. It's outputting an error for me

Comment: The question is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76378933/mapping-null-to-nulable-float-does-not-work-in-automapper