# Mapping DateTime Not Converting to the Correct Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have this mapper, and in the logic of mapping I will check if a property has an attibute CustomDateConverAttribute. If it has, I will call a function to Convert the string to the correct Format:

```
CreateMap<JToken, ModelOne>()

.ForAllMembers(opt =>
{
    opt.MapFrom(src => src.SelectToken(opt.DestinationMember.Name));
    opt.Condition((src, des, _, _, resolutionContext) =>
    {
        MemberInfo propDestination = opt.DestinationMember;
        string propName = propDestination.Name;

        //this is where we modify data with type mappers
        if (Attribute.IsDefined(propDestination, typeof(CustomDateConvertAttribute)))
        {
            opt.ConvertUsing(new CustomDateTimeConverter(), src => src.SelectToken(propName).ToString());
        }

        //map all
        return true;
    });
});
```

And this is what I'm calling:

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter<string, string>
{
    public string Convert(string source, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        try
        {
            dt = DateTime.Parse(source);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return dt.Year + "-" + dt.Month + "-" + dt.Day + " " + dt.Hour + ":" + dt.Minute + ":" + dt.Second;
    }
}
```

However, it's not successfully being converted. How would I be able to convert the time format to the correct value?

**UPDATE**

To answer the question in the comments:
I basically have 2 APIs. One is all `POST` requests to a db. The posted data maps to a model of three properties:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? DataReceived { get; set; }
    public int? Transfered { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Then `DataReceived` accepts `strings` but majority of the data here is `JSON`.

The other API is for transferring the `DataReceived` to models in the second db. That's when I did the AutoMapper.

Comment: Hi,@Prosy Arceno,I couldn't reproduce the issue ,on myside,it works well, could you provide more details of all related codes?

Comment: I narrowed it down to using the `ForAllMembers`. when i switch to ForMember, it works.

Comment: Might you have an idea what's cauising this?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I changed the question, can you help me with this one?

Comment: The question is unclear - what are you trying to convert to begin with? No JSON serializer needs AutoMapper to deserialize to a specific object. DateTime objects are binary values, they have no format. In JSON, the standard way to represent dates is ISO8601 but once deserializes, those dates have no format. Finally, an `IValueConverter<string,string>` isn't a value converter at all, it converts one string to another.

Comment: Why not use JSON.NET or System.Text.Json and just deserialize your JSON to a concrete object? Are you trying to transform the objects at the same time? Then AutoMapper is *1000%* the wrong choice, based [on its author's guidance](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosoph). It's not a transformation tool, it's a convention-based flattener. You could use Json serialization type converters *or* deserialize JSON to objects first, then use eg LINQ and simple methods to map one DTO to another

Comment: Why not use [custom JsonConverters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm)?

Comment: When I debug,it  never get into  the converter,I would try again tomorrow

Comment: Hello @PanagiotisKanavos I've added an explanation on why I'm doing what I'm doing. I'll try to look into custom JsonConverters, but so far autoMapper is working for me. I don't exactly know why this is not the correct approach as the link you've given re the author' guidance is broken.

Comment: JSON is text itself. The explanation doesn't explain anything and AutoMapper is definitely the wrong tool. If you want custom JSON deserialization, use a custom type converter. Unless you mean that `DataReceived` is the *database field* that holds JSON. Once again, AutoMapper is the wrong tool. It's your data loading code that needs to convert the JSON string. Some ORMs, eg EF Core 7, support JSON mapping out of the box. Or, given there's a single property only, you can deserialize the text in the class itself and expose the result as a property

Comment: @ProsyArceno I **strongly** suggest reading [AutoMapper's Design Philosophy](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy) to realize what's wrong and what AutoMapper is really about. If you use EF Core, check [EF Core 7 JSON Support](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/02/14/getting-started-entity-framework-core-7-json-support/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I agree that this might be the wrong tool. I used simple JSON mapping before but when I put it up for review part of their recommendation was to use Automapper. I'm fairly new to C#, much less .Net so I don't have much know-howws to argue. [image](https://pasteboard.co/oMDG4F96lP1A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CustomDateTimeConverter` class implements the `IValueConverter<string, string>` interface. Since the source value is already a string, you don't need to specify the `IValueConverter` interface with string types. Instead, you can simply implement the `IValueConverter<JToken, DateTime>` interface directly.

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter<JToken, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(JToken source, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        string sourceValue = source.ToString();

        DateTime dt;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(sourceValue, out dt))
        {
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sourceValue, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

In the `ForAllMembers` configuration, you should use `opt.MapFrom` to specify the source member for mapping, instead of `src.SelectToken(opt.DestinationMember.Name)`. `src.SelectToken(opt.DestinationMember.Name)` will always return null because `opt.DestinationMember.Name` refers to the destination member's name, not the source member's name.

```
CreateMap<JToken, ModelOne>()
    .ForAllMembers(opt =>
    {
        opt.MapFrom(src => src);
        opt.Condition((src, des, _, _, resolutionContext) =>
        {
            MemberInfo propDestination = opt.DestinationMember;
            string propName = propDestination.Name;

            if (Attribute.IsDefined(propDestination, typeof(CustomDateConvertAttribute)))
            {
                opt.ConvertUsing<CustomDateTimeConverter>();
            }

            return true;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Turns out I didn't need the Condition, I just added your first code, and instead of using JToken, I used string. It's all still pretty confusing but it works